# Why does cirlceCI does not build successfully when renv is part of a R package?

Tags: r, continuous-integration, circleci

Im trying to set up a CI for a R package. In that regard I`m considering circleCI, which has worked out with previous R projects. However this time, I get the following error:

```
 Downloading renv 0.14.0 ... OK (downloaded source)
 Installing renv 0.14.0 ... Done!
 Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.14.0.
 Project '~/main' loaded. [renv 0.14.0]
 devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
 Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘devtools’
 Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
 Execution halted
```

My .circleci/config.yml looks similar to that one

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: my_random_image
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install package dependencies
          command: R -e "devtools::install_deps(dep = TRUE)"
      - run:
          name: Build package
          command: R CMD build .
      - run:
          name: Check package
          command: R CMD check *tar.gz
```

and my_random_image looks as follows:

```
FROM r-base:4.1.2

RUN apt-get update  \
  && apt-get install git libssl-dev ssh texlive-latex-base texlive-fonts-recommended 
libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev -y \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('devtools', 'roxygen2'), repos='http://cran.us.r- project.org')"
```

So its pretty standard stuff, as far as I can see. The error only occurs if `renv` is part if my R package. Otherwise circleCI does not complain and runs as expected without any errors.
I would like to keep `renv` in my R project and therefore struggle to understand the issue and the solution to that.
appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is most likely that your run stage, here:

```
      - run:
          name: Install package dependencies
          command: R -e "devtools::install_deps(dep = TRUE)"
```

installs packages into the default user / site libraries, but when R is launched in your project's working directory:

```
 Downloading renv 0.14.0 ... OK (downloaded source)
 Installing renv 0.14.0 ... Done!
 Successfully installed and loaded renv 0.14.0.
 Project '~/main' loaded. [renv 0.14.0]
```

the `renv` autoloader is automatically downloading `renv`, and activating the `renv` project library.

By default, `renv` *isolates* projects from the user / site library, so the packages installed in your earlier steps are not visible within the project. This behavior is intentional, and ensures that different project libraries are isolated both from changes in the user / site libraries, as well as in other project libraries.

One of the following should help:

1. If your `renv.lock` is up to date, call `renv::restore()` before trying to use `devtools` or other packages;
2. Allow `renv` to see the user library, with e.g. the environment variable `RENV_CONFIG_USER_LIBRARY = TRUE`.

I'd recommend reading https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html and https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/ci.html if you haven't already.